# Problem with terminating input function of python in sublime text 3

Tags: python, sublimetext3

Thank you if you are reading this and for help me.

I wrote a python script in sublime text 3, which uses a input function to take string and to display it using a print function.

I run the script with ctr + B, input command executed, now I write a string and hit enter. Cursor goes in next line and input function did not terminated.

Help me to solve this problem. Thank you.

Comment: Ctrl + C will terminate.

Answer (score 1):

Sublime Text does not support inputting data into a program .

How to solve this problem

- Create a build system that first opens a terminal and then runs your program inside of the terminal
- Use [SublimeREPL](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/SublimeREPL) to run your code in Sublime
- Use [Terminus](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Terminus) in your build system; it allows you to create an actual interactive terminal directly within Sublime.

I would generally recommend Terminus for this; it's very easy

Quick Solution outside sublime :

- can use separate cmd(Windows) or Terminal(Mac/Linux) 
  `python name_file.py`

Answer (score 0):

Click the Sublime Text icon to launch it, or search for Sublime Text in
your system’s search bar and then launch it. Go to Tools Build System4
New Build System, which will open a new configuration file for you. Delete
what you see and enter the following:

```
{
 "cmd": ["python3", "-u", "$file"],
}
```